# Is there a tool that can be observed existing attributes a hbm file?

Tags: nhibernate, mapping, nhibernate-mapping

I have a project using **NHibernate**. The hbm files for mapping is set to manually. But i am not aware of other attributes of fields in hbm file.
Is there a tool that can be observed existing attributes a hbm file?

Comment: Are you looking for a tool that will examine a poco class and mapping file and notify you of any missing properties that have not been mapped?

Comment: Yes. Of course i need more an editor for hbm files.

Comment: there are projects to generate the mappings out of your code. take a look at *Fluent NHibernate* or *NHibernate-mapping-by-code*. you can generate the hbm files with them on every build then include

Comment: Of course I do not need to generate a mapping file for First time. I need to edit some mapping in my project. So I need to a editor for hbm files and I think that `Fluent` not good for me. is Nh-mapping-by-code a good editor?

Answer (score 2):

If your using Visual Studio, just use the xml editor.

To get intellisense, add the nhibernate Schema files located in the nhibernate nuget package located in the packages folder under you solution to the Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Xml\Schemas directory.

**Edit**
I haven't used nst, so I cannot comment on it.  The mapping files are XML files.  Once you get a handle on how they are constructed they are fairly easy to change.  however if you really want to go down the editor route try, http://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper/nhibernate-designer.html

Comment: @Fisher: I added nst.exe to Program Files, But I do not know how work by it. Noteworthy is that i need to a editor **similar** `Microsoft Service Configuration Editor ` for edit of service config in a WCF project or **similar** `Enterprise lLibrary Configuration 5 ` for edit config of a application by logging implementation. is nst a good editor for me?